# Footer does not stick to the bottom

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

here's my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HSVBuzzp1IIDjFdbuf4E?p=preview

in short: I cannot find a way to put the footer at the bottom of the page.

I tried to just rely on html:

```
<footer></footer>
```

I tried using bootstrap ui's class:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
```

or

```
<div id="footer">
   <div class="container">
    ...
</div>
```

but nothing...It just doesn't seem working...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out:
http://plnkr.co/edit/caLGN05wzH3Ls2PcRoTe?p=preview

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.modal-footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I have added some more css in the head of the page.
Firstly, if you inspect the page, the length of the body is only half of the page. So we have to give it height 100% so that it takes the whole page.

Secondly, to place footer at the bottom of the page, we need to position it as **absolute** so that it aligns itself to its first positioned parent(in this case none, as we have not specified position to any other element), and then you can specify **bottom** as 0 so that it sticks to the bottom.

This is the normal way in which we can put footer at the bottom. You can check if bootstrap might have something inbuilt.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it works but now the straight line delimiting the footer itself just stops midway..

Comment: That is the width issue as we have not specified any width. You need to set the width of the modal-footer to 100%. See modified CSS above.

Comment: you saved my day